# Hover transition effect for Button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I try to add a one-second transition from the normal color scheme to the hovering color for the Button element in Material UI. I use the method `transitions.create(props, options)` talked here in this article: https://medium.com/@octaviocoria/custom-css-transitions-with-react-material-ui-5d41cb2e7c5. Actually the transition can work, but the hovering color will also appear immediately on the button as long as the mouse hovers on it. How can I stop the color change immediately but wait for the transition to make it change.

Related code:

```
function Mbutton({ classes }) {
  return (
    <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.cart} disableRipple>
      Add to Cart
    </Button>
  );
}

const styles = theme => ({
  cart: {
    padding: "6px 16px",
    borderRadius: 0,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    "&:hover": {
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["backgroundColor", "color"], {
        duration: 1000
      }),
      backgroundColor: "#000",
      color: "#fff"
    }
  }
});
```

Also can check it on Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mbutton-fogco

Thanks.

Comment: The first argument of `theme.transitions.create` should be the CSS property name, not the style written in JSX. So the backgroundColor should be **background-color**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like you do in plain CSS

```
const styles = theme => ({
    cart: {
        padding: "6px 16px",
        borderRadius: 0,
        border: "2px solid #000",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        color: "black",
        transition: "background 1s, color 1s",
        "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        color: "#fff"
        }
    }
});
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mbutton-3y1xs)

The theme passed is unnecessary, you should only use that if you want to use the transition styles available on the default Material-UI theme object, which you didn't need it here.

Comment: It still behaves the same way. The effect I hope is when the mouse hovers on the button, the background color turns from white to black while the words inside turn black to white in 1 second. But hovering scheme (black background with the white words) always appears immediately when hovering. This is not what I want.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Seems I just make it too complex. BTW, with `theme` it can work too. A misunderstanding in my code leads to the wrong behavior. See my comments on my own thread.